# How to detect class change on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, class, propertychanged

I have click action on some element after it changes class, I need to detect this moment and do something. For other browsers than IE i use `MutationObserve`, but IE doesn't support this feture so i use `OnPropChanged` but something is not right, can anybody tell me what?

```
element.click(function(){
   function OnPropChanged (event) {
       if (event.propertyName.toLowerCase () == "class") {
           alert ("The new content: " + event.srcElement.value);
       }
   }
   observe_target.attachEvent ("onpropertychange", OnPropChanged);
)};
```

Much thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

The property name is "className", not "class" (although the attribute's name is "class"). Also, if you really want to attach the event on click, make sure the element is only clickable once, or you'll get multiple event handlers observing the same property.